# accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, accessoryview

I am creating a Detail disclosure button which is getting populated using an array.... However the accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: function is not being called in my class. It is a `TableviewDelegate` and `TableviewDatasource` delegate.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"reaching accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"modaltodetails" sender:[self.eventsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
}
```

The NSLog isnt printing to console which leads me to believe the function isnt being called... This is of course when I select on a cell. A screenshot below shows how I have my cell setup.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you connected the dataSource & delegate to the appropriate class? Does the 
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
method get called?

Comment: yes (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath is getting called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you just click on the cell to select it or did you actually click on the accessory button indicator on the cell? It isn't clear from your question.

`accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` is applicable when you click on the button icon within the cell and not when you select the cell.

Comment: have you made all the necessary connections..both tableview data source and delegate to the file owner?

Comment: did u find out what the problem was?

Answer (score 64):

The doc says that the method [`tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614996-tableview) is not called when an accessory view is set for the row at `indexPath`. The method is only called when the `accessoryView` property is `nil` and when one uses and set the `accessoryType` property to display a built-in accessory view.

As I understand it, `accessoryView` and `accessoryType` are mutually exclusive. When using `accessoryType`, the system will call `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` as expected, but you have to handle the other case by yourself.

The way Apple does this is shown in the `Accessory` sample project of the SDK. In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of the dataSource delegate, they set a target/action to a custom accessory button. Since one can't pass the `indexPath` to the action, they call an auxiliary method to retrieve the corresponding `indexPath` and they pass the result to the delegate method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ...

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    ...

    // set the button's target to this table view controller so we can interpret touch events and map that to a NSIndexSet
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    ...
    cell.accessoryView = button;

    return cell;
}


- (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil){
        [self tableView: self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
    }
}
```

For some reason, your setup seems to fall in the accessoryView case. Have you tried to set the `accessoryType` with code instead of using the Interface Builder ?

Comment: I've run into the same issue and I'm wondering whether there is a bug in Xcode 4.5 IB that is setting an `AccessoryView` rather than an `AccesoryType` when you select the Accessory in the TableViewCell inspector pane.  If you create a segue by clicking and dragging from the disclosure indicator that doesn't work either!

Comment: Quick update - it appears that if you set the accessory type to `DetailDisclosure` rather than just plain `Disclosure`, the  `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` method gets called and a triggered segue works.  I can't work out why yet, but at least you can make some headway (even if your UI doesn't look the way you want it to).

Comment: So is this a bug in Xcode, or intended behavior? Apple's docs are distressingly unclear on this. There are two types of disclosure indicators on a table cell, plain Disclosure and Detail Disclosure, but the docs just say "the disclosure button".

Comment: _they set a target/action to a custom accessory button_ isn't that a little dumb? I mean if I want to go through that trouble then I'd just subclass the the tableviewcell and a button there myself!

Answer (score 39):

This seems very relevant...

**Disclosure indicator**: When this element is present, users know they can tap anywhere in the row to see the next level in the hierarchy or the choices associated with the list item. Use a disclosure indicator in a row when selecting the row results in the display of another list. Don’t use a disclosure indicator to reveal detailed information about the list item; instead, use a detail disclosure button for this purpose.

**Detail disclosure button**: Users tap this element to see detailed information about the list item. (Note that you can use this element in views other than table views, to reveal additional details about something; see “Detail Disclosure Buttons” for more information.) In a table view, use a detail disclosure button in a row to display details about the list item. Note that the detail disclosure button, unlike the disclosure indicator, can perform an action that is separate from the selection of the row. For example, in Phone Favorites, tapping the row initiates a call to the contact; tapping the detail disclosure button in the row reveals more information about the contact.

Comment: Link for more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Controls.html

Answer (score 12):

Converting the top answer to Swift 3:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    let unseletcedImage = UIImage(named: "<imagename>")
    let seletcedImage = UIImage(named: "<imagename>")
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    // match the button's size with the image size
    let frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0.0), y: CGFloat(0.0), width: CGFloat((unseletcedImage?.size.width)!), height: CGFloat((unseletcedImage?.size.height)!))
    button.frame = frame
    button.setBackgroundImage(unseletcedImage, for: .normal)
    button.setBackgroundImage(seletcedImage, for: .selected)
    cell?.accessoryView = button
    let action = #selector(checkButtonTapped(sender:event:))
    (cell?.accessoryView as? UIButton)?.addTarget(self, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
    ....
    return cell!

}

@objc func checkButtonTapped(sender: UIButton?, event: UIEvent) {
    let touches = event.allTouches
    let touch = touches!.first
    guard let touchPosition = touch?.location(in: self.tableView) else {
        return
    }
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPosition) {
        tableView(self.tableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

According to UITableViewCellAccessoryType's documentation it is expected behaviour:

```
typedef enum : NSInteger {    
UITableViewCellAccessoryNone,   
UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator,   
UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton,   
UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark,   
UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton } UITableViewCellAccessoryType;
```

> Constants UITableViewCellAccessoryNone The cell does not have any
>   accessory view. This is the default value.
>
> UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator The cell has an accessory
>   control shaped like a chevron. This control indicates that tapping the
>   cell triggers a push action. The control **does not track** touches.
>
> UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton The cell has an info
>   button and a chevron image as content. This control indicates that
>   tapping the cell allows the user to configure the cell’s contents. The
>   control **tracks** touches.
>
> UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark The cell has a check mark on its
>   right side. This control **does not track** touches. The delegate of the
>   table view can manage check marks in a section of rows (possibly
>   limiting the check mark to one row of the section) in its
>   tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method.
>
> UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton The cell has an info button
>   without a chevron. This control indicates that tapping the cell
>   displays additional information about the cell’s contents. The control
>   **tracks** touches.

Answer (score 2):

drew is spot on.

If you change to 'DetailDisclosure' in Storyboard, then the method will fire.  (xCode 4.6 DP3)

Answer (score 2):

My tableView's `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath(…)` was not being called when the Detail disclosure button was hit.  I eventually found that the problem was simply that tableView delegate had not been set:

`self.tableView.delegate = self`

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to handle the disclosure button using the storyboard.  You should click the table view cell and goto the Connections Inspector.   There is a section called Triggered Segues, and you can drag from the selection line to the UIViewController that you want to segue to.  The segue will happen automatically and you can capture prepareForSegue to capture the notification when it does.
The function accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath never gets called for the disclosure button.  It only gets called for the detailed disclosure button.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Swift 5.7 / iOS 16 (obviously would work in much earlier versions)

This solution makes use of nested functions to keep handlers and setup local to limited use cases.

```
    extension MyViewController : UITableViewDelegate {
    
        @objc func findRowOfTappedButton(sender: UIButton?, event: UIEvent) {
            let touches = event.allTouches
            let touch = touches!.first
            guard let touchPosition = touch?.location(in: self.tableView) else { return }
                if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPosition) {
                   tableView(self.tableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith: indexPath)
             }
        }

        // Note: By implementing the following handler as appropriate delegate method,
        // the scheme will still work if accessoryType changes to OS-provided type.

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
            tableView.delegate?.tableView!(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)

             // Do whatever when button at this row is pressed.
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
             return 44
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

             // Do whatever when row is selected w/o button press.
        }

    }

    extension MyViewController : UITableViewDataSource {

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
           return 1
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return myContent.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            func addAccessoryButtonToCell(_ cell : UITableViewCell) {
                let image = UIImage(systemName: "paintpalette")
                let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
                button.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 20, height: 20)
                button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
                button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(findRowOfTappedButton(sender:event:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                cell.accessoryView = button
            }

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyReusableCell", for: indexPath)
            addAccessoryButtonToCell()            
            content.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: myContent[indexPath.row], attributes: myAttributes[indexPath.row])
        }
    }
```