# UITableViewCell Accessory taped dont work

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have the custom UITableViewCell and this code to create the accessory

```
    UIImage *indicatorImage  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Map.png"];

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [button setImage:indicatorImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)];
    cell.accessoryView = button;
```

and i have this two methods:

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath        *)indexPath
   {
//[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToDetail" sender:self];
NSLog(@"row");
    }


 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

//[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToMap" sender:self];
NSLog(@"accessory");
   }
```

I would like to capture two different events: 1 for the row and one for the accessory, with the two methods that I put above I can only get the event for the row. How do I get the accessory?

help please

Comment: it should work similar to the way target has been specified to the button. You only need to add target to your button to make it work.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296904/accessorybuttontappedforrowwithindexpath-not-getting-called

Comment: I found this solution...

Comment: i added this row to my button:                                      [button addTarget:self action:@selector(methodTouchDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

Comment: and then i use this metod: -(void)methodTouchDown:(id)sender

Comment: You should use touchUpInside, not touchDown.

Comment: If you got something to work @liberosoftware, please add it as the answer and accept it =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in every row i add this button that i set like an accessory:

```
 UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [button setImage:indicatorImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(methodTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.accessoryView = button;
```

now i create this metod

```
   -(void)methodTouchUpInside:(id)sender
```

every time we tap on a button in a row , he call this meted.  to select the button that call him we can use button.tag!