# Distinguish between accessoryView and Row on touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessory

I want users to get a different result if they click on an accessory image in a table cell rather than the row.

To capture their tap on the accessory, I am using following method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;{
NSLog(@"accessory button tapped");
  }
```

In addition, I am not using the standard indicators.  Instead, I am using custom images as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 [cell setAccessoryView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark.png"]]];

}
```

that overrides the standard accessory button and shows an image.  Note: It shows the image no matter what the disclosure indicator is set to in storyboard, none, checkmark, disclosure indicator, etc.

However, currently, the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;{
NSLog(@"accessory button tapped");
  }
```

method is not firing.

There are some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296904/accessorybuttontappedforrowwithindexpath-not-getting-called) on SO that suggest this method is not called if the accessory is an accessory view as opposed to accessory type.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use custom images and still get button tapped method to fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe a `;` in your method signature even before body starts:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;{
}
```

As a side note from [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:):

> Discussion The delegate usually responds to the tap on the disclosure
>   button (the accessory view) by displaying a new view related to the
>   selected row. This method is not called when an accessory view is set
>   for the row at indexPath.

This method is used for identifying touches on disclosure indicator and not on accessory view.

In order to support your accessory view touches, create custom `UITableViewCell`and add an `UITapGestureRecognizer` on your accessory view to intercept the taps.

Comment: Do you need to create a custom class for custom cell?

Comment: You need to subclass UITableViewCell.

Comment: The semicolon is legal and does not affect the method definition.

Answer (score 3):

You can add tag gesture on UIImageView by

```
UIImageView *imgView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark.png"]];
imgView.tag = indexPath.row;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapGesture:)];
tapGesture1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[tapGesture1 setDelegate:self];
[imgView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture1];
[cell setAccessoryView:];
```

And add selector method

```
- (void) tapGesture: (id)sender
{
    //handle Tap...
}
```

Hope it help

Comment: Would I have to put this in a custom cell?