# accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath not working for custom button or label

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiaccessoryview

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let key =  keyArray[indexPath.section-1]
      let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 26, 28))
      label.center = CGPointMake(26, 28)
      cell.accessoryView = label
}

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print(indexPath)
    }
```

Why for custom label or custom button not call `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` . Or only one way add myButton to cell ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For custom button you can add target for specific event, `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` will not work for custom view

Please refer:

[image]

Comment: can you please share a doc that mention not working with custom Button. because here said http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296904/accessorybuttontappedforrowwithindexpath-not-getting-called

Comment: that question is for native button